# How do I install the "Impact" font?

Tags: fonts, font-manager

I was wondering what's the best way to go about this. I don't have it available in Kdenlive or GIMP so I don't think it's installed.

The `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package doesn't work for me, it constantly shows an error of ["Failed to download extra data files"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1607535). There's probably a different way to install this one font...

Comment: @muru No, I'm not getting that error @digiwizkid That answer suggests using the Ubuntu Software Center which has been made obsolete and also the `ttf-` package doesn't work. My question is about whether there's a better way to install it than just manually copying a .ttf file into a folder (aka, what's the *best* way?).

Comment: Well, that's the error you mentioned. The best way is to use the package, which suffers from a bug, which has a workaround, described in both the post I linked to, and the bug report you linked to.

Comment: Their error is that the sub-script is stuck at [Waiting for headers] but mine just has lots of lines that say "Can't download" and the script completes, unsuccessfully.

Comment: Their problem is also that the downloads fail, it just tries to spend time downloading for the files.

Comment: This question should be reopened. These "Duplicates" are general "learn how to fish", not specific "how to catch a trout". Considering this is the first result on google when I search for "ubuntu impact font", It should have a specific answer here, and not one that requires me to first learn how to install fonts in general, with no context to "impact" and whatever license it falls under.

Comment: Here in 2021 in Ubuntu 18.04 this appears to work fine by running `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is to download Debian's version of this package:

https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download

Then the fonts install without any problems! Hooray, and curse Ubuntu for failing to create a functional package when they could've just copied Debian's version and had it work!

Comment: Ubuntu *DID* just copy Debian's package. Curse your assumptions.

Comment: @user535733: ??

Comment: @user535733 False, because if they did, it would work, I downloaded the package directly from Debian and it worked, but Ubuntu's copy doesn't, therefore these are not the same file and aren't copies.

Comment: @AaronFranke there mare many possible reasons why your attempt to install the Ubuntu package didn't work. Some people here are quite good at narrowing those possibilities, identifying the real problem, and fixing it. Jumping to conclusions is indeed fun, but it skips over that important step of troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: @user535733 Whatever conclusions you can draw doesn't change the fact that the Ubuntu package is faulty and the Debian package is functional.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I need specific instructions on how to download and install it